# matlab to vhdl code generation. Function rand is not supported in float to fixed point conversion

Tags: matlab, vhdl, hdl

I am trying to convert my matlab files to vhdl code.I am using hdl coder for that.During the hdl code generation process,I am getting an error in step:3"generate fixed point code".The error showing is 
Function 'rand' is not supported in float to fixed point conversion.

Please help

Comment: Can you show us some of the code?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear - you need to use a function other than `rand()` if you are hoping to generate VHDL code from it.

You may want to research pseudo-random number generators.